# Compileing my blank console application with a setup Microsoft visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, dll, windows-installer, setup-project

so i have a console application that stitches a pdf into one big long tif however when i go to make a setup project it all seems to work fine until i move the installer to another commutator and run it it installs fine however whenever i run the application it gives an error

```
The program can't start because ucrtbassed.dll is missing from your computer
```

i have seen videos where when they add the primary output some msm file is added depending on the library's used in he code however no such file appears when i add my output in the application folder section in the main setup file

edit::
i feel that i cant explain this correctly and thus will upload it as and image this is the main application file inside of the setup project it looks like its only copying  the source code when it should also include some dlls

[application folder on the setup wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1PkH.png)

Comment: Please see [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons you should **not** post images of your code, and then see the [ask] page in the [help] here. Then come back and [edit] your question to include the relevant information in your post as text that is useful to us. When you do so, include the **exact error message** you're getting; *along the lines of something about some dll* is absolutely useless as a problem description. If you want help from us, put the effort into writing a specific question.

Comment: will do and sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

You are shipping a debug version of your app, and it is failing because it is asking for the debug version of the Universal CRT (that's why there is a "d" on the end, and it's actually ucrtbased.dll). In general the debug versions of these are available for debugging on developer's machines, not for client machines. So build a release version of your app and see what it does. If it fails looking for ucrtbase.dll, then clients can use this to install it:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48234